# Unable to decode media issue on chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, html5-video, media

I am experiencing an issue while playing media on my application. I am using html5 player which works fine on another browser but the media not worked on Google Chrome. Below is the ffmpeg output.

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma

  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100

  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100

  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100

  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100

  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100

  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0

  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100

  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100

  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sources-5a6b388fb093f.mp4':

  Metadata:

    major_brand     : mp42

    minor_version   : 0

    compatible_brands: mp42mp41

    creation_time   : 2017-10-31T01:45:10.000000Z

  Duration: 00:04:55.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10300 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 9975 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)

    Metadata:

      creation_time   : 2017-10-31T01:45:10.000000Z

      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler

      encoder         : AVC Coding

    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)

    Metadata:

      creation_time   : 2017-10-31T01:45:10.000000Z

      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
```

The issue is replicable on Windows, Linux/Ubuntu and Mac on Google Chrome browser.

**UPDATED:**

```
render_id: 56
player_id: 0
origin_url: https://example.com/
frame_url: https://example.com/node/83810
frame_title: 
url: https://example.com/sites/default/files/sources-5a6b388fb093f.mp4
total_bytes: 380754023
streaming: false
single_origin: true
passed_cors_access_check: false
range_header_supported: true
pipeline_state: kStopped
info: Selected FFmpegVideoDecoder for video decoding, config: codec: h264 format: 1 profile: h264 main coded size: [1920,1080] visible rect: [0,0,1920,1080] natural size: [1920,1080] has extra data? true encryption scheme: Unencrypted rotation: 0°
audio_channels_count: 2
audio_codec_name: aac
audio_sample_format: Float 32-bit planar
audio_samples_per_second: 48000
bitrate: 10300299
found_audio_stream: true
found_video_stream: true
height: 1080
max_duration: 295.722667
start_time: 0
time_base: 1/60000
video_codec_name: h264
video_format: PIXEL_FORMAT_I420
video_is_encrypted: false
width: 1920
audio_dds: false
audio_decoder: FFmpegAudioDecoder
video_dds: false
video_decoder: FFmpegVideoDecoder
audio_buffering_state: BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
video_buffering_state: BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
for_suspended_start: false
pipeline_buffering_state: BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
duration: 295.722667
event: PAUSE
error: video decode error
pipeline_error: PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE
```

Added chrome Player Properties for specific media.

Comment: After the video fails to play, open a new tab, type `chrome://media-internals/` as the address and inspect the media pipeline for your file. Also, you could share the file, the ffmpeg output is quite useless.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: Added the Player Properties for the media.